# Creating a list of dictionaries with values added dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Objective**: I receive the number of clients as input and i need to create a dictionary in the following format only as the server reads in the same format (one key , i.e. 'cdata' and a list of dictionaries as values).

**Example**: If i receive 4 clients  as input from user , then the following should be generated. (so it should generate the values dynamically based on user input)

FYI : I am trying to simulate multiple clients on a single machine.

```
 jsondata = json.dumps(
            {'cdata': [
                { 'cname': "client1", 'heart': val1, 'timC': tstamp, 'sig': random.uniform(0,10)},
                { 'cname': "client2", 'heart': val2,  'timC': tstamp, 'sig': random.uniform(0,10)},
                { 'cname': "client3", 'heart': val3,  'timC': tstamp, 'sig': random.uniform(0,10)},
                { 'cname': "client4", 'heart': val4,  'timC': tstamp, 'sig': random.uniform(0,10)}
            ]
            }, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'), indent=2)
```

Apologies if its a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
values = [val1, val2, val3, val4] #val variables
tstamp = 'something'

result = {'cdata': [{'cname': 'client{}'.format(i), 'heart': val, 'timC': tstamp, 'sig': random.uniform(0,10)} for i, val in enumerate(values, 1)]}
```

Now you can just dump result to `json`:

```
jsondata = json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'), indent=2)
```